# Map SQL on Predicates

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, predicates

I have some SQL

```sql
select id, name from table where id = '1' and  name = 'A'
                             or  id = '2' and  name = 'B'
                             or  id = '3' and  name = 'C';
```

Result of SQL satisfies me, but anyway I have to map that SQL to JPA's Predicates.

What I have now

```java
List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

Predicate id1 = criteriaBuilder.like(root.get(id), "%" + "1" + "%");
predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.and(id1));

Predicate nameA = criteriaBuilder.like(root.get(name), "%" + "A" + "%");
predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.and(nameA));

Predicate id2 = criteriaBuilder.like(root.get(id), "%" + "2" + "%");
predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.and(id2));

Predicate name2 = criteriaBuilder.like(root.get(name), "%" + "B" + "%");
predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.and(name2));

Predicate id3 = criteriaBuilder.like(root.get(id), "%" + "3" + "%");
predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.and(id3));

Predicate name3 = criteriaBuilder.like(root.get(name), "%" + "C" + "%");
predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.and(name3));

query.where(criteriaBuilder.or(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()])));
return entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

Query of Predicates return also some redundant data, except of SQL query.

Please correct my Predicate condition in order to get the same result as from sql query.

Many thanks!

Comment: what do you mean for reduntant ?

Comment: There are another data that matched on that criteria. For example  
there is  row with name A but id is 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write something likethat  :

```
Predicate id1 = criteriaBuilder.like(root.get(id), "%" + "1" + "%");
Predicate nameA = criteriaBuilder.like(root.get(name), "%" + "A" + "%");

    Predicate id1nameA = criteriaBuilder.and(id1,nameA);
    predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.or(id1nameA));
    //...continue for the others
```

Anyway using **like** its different than **=** so it can make such issue .

> If your jpa implementation is Hibernate you can show sql to console by adding the follow lines of code in your **persistence.xml**

```
<properties>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="..somethinginhere.."/>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
</properties>
```